# When should I use XML files over Database? And if storing large data in XML files is inefficient, Does XML databases solve that problem?

Tags: xml, database, xml-parsing, xml-database

I also read that parsing XML files is a painful process, why is that ?

As far as I know , Java provides parsing libraries such as DOM and SAX. Whats hard about using those libraries ? is it the size of the XML file that causes the problem ?

Comment: Sorry, StackOverflow takes some getting used to. One of the rules that people enforce quite strictly is that only coding questions are allowed: questions about application architecture, evaluation of alternative technologies, etc, are strongly discouraged. One of the reasons is that no-one who is actually competent and experienced in the area you are asking about would dream of giving you an answer without first conducting a serious study of your requirements and project constraints. Try again on the xml-dev mailing list at xml.org, where you will get a dozen different well-informed opinions.

Comment: Oh, and another of the StackOverflow rules, which helps a great deal in keeping the discussion focused, is that you should only ask one question per thread. You actually managed to squeeze in five.

Comment: Sorry for not being careful , thank you.